# Is the term "Indian spammer" offensive?

Tags: discussion, moderation, code-of-conduct, offensive

I recently encountered a post here on Meta Stack Exchange that was worded very similarly to a poorly-received post by a now-suspended user. I flagged the post as relating to a likely sock-puppet of that suspended user. My flag was marked *Helpful*, but it included an extra comment of "Looks more like some poor Indian spammer guy copy-pasting existing content to me. They were just unlucky enough to pick some of [Suspended User]'s content."

Now, I'm not questioning the disposition of the flag, the posts in question, or either of the user accounts, but I am concerned about the phraseology "Indian spammer". Is using this kind of phraseology, that associates a negative, antisocial behavior (spamming) with an ethnic group who stereotypically engages in that sort of behavior (Indians) offensive and/or racist? One might compare it to other, similar ethnic accusations, such as "Sicilian mobster", "Drunk Irishman", "Drunk Native American", "Scheming Jew", "Arab terrorist", "Nigerian scammer", or a French person who surrenders easily.

Also to be clear, I'm not Indian and didn't feel personally offended by the remark, but my concern is what if I *was* Indian and had been offended by that remark? Should we avoid the use of these terms on the site in general?

In response to Dan Mašek's question about what phrase I would use instead, I would just say "a spammer". How would you like to get a call, "This is the North Dakota State Police. I'm sorry to inform you that your child was run over by a drunk Native American in a truck"? Would you care to know the ethnic background of the perpetrator under that circumstance or would you be more concerned about other things? In the case above, the user is alleged to be a spammer. Knowing that they are, or may be, Indian doesn't give me any useful information I can act on and just cements into my mind the stereotype of Indians as inveterate spammers, just looking for any opportunity to shill their dietary supplements, online casinos, Windows repair services, and other dubious deals without regard to whether they are in a place where it is appropriate to do so.

Comment: Personally, I'd just assume the spammer is accessing the site from an Indian IP, unless there's further context to the contrary.

Comment: What V2Blast said

Comment: Suppose it was a stereotype. What other phrase would you use to describe a person from said country performing the activity in question? There has to be some limit to this sort of self-censorship (or whatever you wanna call it), or soon enough we won't be able to communicate at all.

Comment: Why would it be offensive to be specific about the observed evidence?

Comment: @W.O. because the additional information is not actionable by the user (what am I going to do, bomb Mumbai because of all the Indian spammers?) and reinforces stereotypes. See my comment above about the "drunk Native American" who commits alcohol-related offenses.

Comment: Noida actually. Its mostly Noida.

Comment: Personally, I'd like to see stats published regarding the country of origin of our spam-load. It's frankly only likely to reinforce stereotypes in people who are predisposed to stereotype. Why should information be censored on the basis that there are people who would misuse/misunderstand it - when as an alternative it might be better to *get the facts* and then challenge those who are predisposed to prejudice to deconstruct their prejudices in light of the facts? @RobertColumbia

Comment: While we should all strive not to perpetuate stereotypes, it also possible such a statement could be obviously accurate based on the content. There's quite a bit of spam seen on SE that's easily identifiable as being of Indian origin and/or targeted to an Indian audience (e.g., services are only available in an Indian city/region, uses Indian telephone numbers without supplying a country code, has prices denominated in INR, links to a site in India, etc.). Without knowing what you flagged, it's impossible to know if calling the spammer an "Indian spammer" was strictly factual.

Comment: @RobertColumbia "*because the additional information is not actionable by the use*"  but how is your preferred information "spammer" actionable by you? It seems it's not yet you aren't upset about including that unactionable part, you're upset and bringing up the nationality which you also cannot do anything about. In fact, what part of that information you think you can personally do anything about? It seems to me the answer is "none" but maybe you can do something about copying content or luck.

Comment: If the spam had originated from France and the message said "French spammer", would that be offensive? or are only certain nationalities offensive to mention?

Comment: We’re not even going to talk about the sexist assumption the spammer was a guy? :) I really miss the “presume good intentions” from the old CoC. I would rather have people feel free to write like human beings than try to proactively sanitize everything into robo-feedback.

Comment: Is there a name for the fallacy of using absolute numbers instead of [per capita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_capita)? Using absolute numbers, the large countries in terms of population will almost always be on top, no matter the measure (positive or negative).

Answer (score 16):

When handling flags, mods get 200 characters to explain why they did what they did. That's less than a tweet and doesn't allow for elaborate sentences. So a user with an Indian name, profile spamming content from India, becomes an Indian spammer.

Regardless of whether it is offensive to call a profile with an Indian name profile spamming content from India an Indian spammer, I shall save those six characters for better usage next time.

Comment: Fun fact? If the "poor Indian spammer" still hadn't fit within the character limit it would probably have been just a "poor spammer". Guess even stricter character limits are needed!

Comment: *Poomer* is even shorter!

Answer (score 16):

I'd say if someone asked you to stop - it'd be a good idea, but there's no need to tiptoe around it.

> My flag was marked Helpful, but it included an extra comment of "Looks more like some poor Indian spammer guy copy-pasting existing content to me. They were just unlucky enough to pick some of [Suspended User]'s content."

As a former moderator here - (and someone of indian origin), that's exactly what I'd say

Contextually - least IME, many but not all of a certain class of spammer come from the Indian subcontinent - though that includes Pakistan or Bangladesh. *Overwhelmingly* it comes from a handful of urban conglomerations in India tho.

We also have, say propaganda spam that's aimed at an enemy of the Chinese communist party. I refer to this *factually* as Chinese propaganda spam. We also have spam referring to the beauty of some random Chinese tourist site in charmingly flawed machine translation and lots of unintelligible filler. This is *probably* Chinese spammers. Sometimes one does need to call a spade a spade.

Also it feels like you're reading a little deeply into a quick bit of feedback  meant to let you know why a flag was acted on as it was.

Also, it would be really nice if people didn't get offended on our behalf. We can, to some extent speak out about implied or institutional racism on our own.  This, to me doesn't count at all, as a former member of the moderation team.

Comment: There's also that kid from India who DDoS'ed SE and targeted Tim Post personally, you remember? That's the first association for me when seeing "Indian spammer" though he wasn't really a spammer, just some bored troll.

Comment: Indian Hacker Team? We arn't really sure if it was indian, hacker or a team tho

Comment: No, so maybe it's something different, and he didn't DDoSed. See [this](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=1781369#1781369), it's when Tim was personally targeted by that troll.

Comment: If he was truely psycic he would have seen it coming, so he clearly was not psysic...

Answer (score -3):

> Should we avoid the use of these terms on the site in general?

I think we should.

- It adds no value to the response given.
- As far as possible, focus should be more on the action and less on the user and definitely not on user's nationality, whether they are rich or poor, or whether they're male or female or even on their username or profile picture or PII. These factors shouldn't be considered at all, unless necessary to the facts of the case. Here, since the allegation is sock-puppetry, I believe  most of these need to be looked into - however, there's absolutely no need to mention/leak such information to the flagger.
- It definitely could be construed as racism and therefore should be avoided.

  - Firstly, Even if it isn't racism, Why take any risk of accusation, when there's no profit?
  - Secondly, The answers above also say there's "truth" in saying an "action"(such as spamming) is generally associated with a "region"(such as Indian subcontinent). But so is any other type of racism described by OP(Drunk Irishman or Arab terrorist). Truth or *strength of association* doesn't make it not racism. Racism is the prejudice/discrimination, which may have some known association. It becomes a problem when there's generalisation of the same association to specific cases. Therefore, the known association shouldn't be phrased/repeated to avoid magnifying the actual association to irrational levels. The [discrimination section of abusive behavior policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct/abusive-behavior) should be considered:

  > Bigotry & Discrimination – *the poor treatment*, **expressed irrational suspicion**, hatred, **targeting**, and/or intolerance of another person or **group of people due to their ethnicity**, age, sexual orientation, gender identity and expression, disability, or held religious beliefs.

  - Was there expressed suspicion due to their ethnicity? I believe so.
  - Was the expressed suspicion irrational though?  Probably not, because of the alleged known association between ethnicity and spam.
  - Was there targeting due to ethnicity? Probably yes.
  - Was there *poor treatment* given to the poster, based on ethnicity? Hard to say.

It's a judgment call on CoC violation, but these phrases relating to one's nationality should definitely be avoided.

A better response would be

> User seems to copy/paste existing content repeatedly and doesn't seem to be a sock puppet

Comment: "Poor" as in doing a very poor job of spamming, not as in 'has no money'.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell   How do we know that for sure ;)? If "indian spam" just means "spammer from India", couldn't we also construe "poor" as materially poor?